# Unmerge or fill in columns in pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that when printed in terminal or sent to an excel file looks like the below.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 112      Martin Messenger Bag                  MRKT-15-0004  Accessories Watch by Featured Host       NaN |
| 262      Fauna Pouch Kitten                    AREA-15-0050  Accessories Watch by Featured Host       NaN |
| 263      Key Cable                             NATI-15-0005  Gadgets     Featured                     NaN |
|                                                                          Gadgets                      NaN |
|                                                                          Summer Staples               NaN |
| 110      Winter Remedy Pack                    ECOA-15-0002  Home Goods  Home Goods                   NaN |
| 109      Travel Set                            ECOA-15-0001  Beauty      Featured                     NaN |
| 274      Ideal Notebook for iPhone             MOLLA-15-0014 Gadgets     Watch by Featured Host       NaN |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Currently item 263 when sent to excel merges the cells.  What is the best way to go about filling in the data for the two merged rows?  Is this a case for `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`?

Edit:  I am writing the excel file with the XlsxWriter library

Answer (score 4):

`merge_cells` is an option that defaults to `True`.  Try setting it to `False`.

```
df.to_excel(merge_cells=False)
```

Comment: Should have mentioned this in the topic, but i am using the XlsxWriter library, not pandas built-in excel writing. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html

Comment: In which case I think `reset_index()` would be your best bet.